# How do I run a function inside an action in Sprite Kit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have the following code for a game I am making. In one of the parts, I have

```
let spawn = SKAction.run {
    self.createCars()
}
```

but for some reason I keep getting an error saying "Value of type '(NSObject -> () -> GameScene' has no member 'createCars' even though createCars is a function defined lower in my code. Why is this happening and what can I do to fix this?

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    var lanecounter:CGFloat = 0
    var score:Int = 0
    var player:SKSpriteNode?
    let scoreLabel = SKLabelNode()
    let highScoreLabel = SKLabelNode()
    var direction:Int?
    let noCategory:UInt32 = 0
    let carCategory:UInt32 = 0b1
    let playerCategory:UInt32 = 0b1 << 1
    let pointCategory:UInt32 = 0b1 << 2
    var died:Bool?
    var restartBTN = SKSpriteNode()

    let moveLeft:SKAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: -100, y: 0, duration: 0.065)
    let moveRight:SKAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: 100, y: 0, duration: 0.065)
    let moveDown:SKAction = SKAction.moveTo(y: -800, duration: 1.1)

    let spawn = SKAction.run {
        self.createCars()
    }

    let delay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 4)

    func createCars(){
        let middlePoints = SKSpriteNode()
        var openLane:CGFloat = 0

        middlePoints.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 10)
        middlePoints.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: middlePoints.size)
        //middlePoints.color = SKColor.purple
        middlePoints.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = pointCategory
        middlePoints.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = playerCategory
        middlePoints.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = playerCategory

        var randInt:Int = 0
        randInt = Int(arc4random_uniform(3))

        if lanecounter == -2 {
            if randInt == 0 || randInt == 1 {
                openLane = -1
            }
            if randInt == 2 {
                openLane = -2
            }
        }

        if lanecounter == 2 {
            if randInt == 0 || randInt == 1 {
                openLane = 1
            }
            if randInt == 2 {
                openLane = 2
            }
        }
        if lanecounter == -1 || lanecounter == 0 || lanecounter == 1 {
            if randInt == 0 {
                openLane = lanecounter - 1
            }
            if randInt == 1 {
                openLane = lanecounter
            }
            if randInt == 2 {
                openLane = lanecounter + 1
            }
        }
        //print("lanecounter is", lanecounter)
        //print("open lane is", openLane)

        if openLane != -2 {
            spawnCar(xCord: -2)
        }
        if openLane != -1 {
            spawnCar(xCord: -1)
        }
        if openLane != 0 {
            spawnCar(xCord: 0)
        }
        if openLane != 1 {
            spawnCar(xCord: 1)
        }
        if openLane != 2 {
            spawnCar(xCord: 2)
        }

        middlePoints.position = CGPoint(x: (openLane*100), y: self.frame.height)

        self.addChild(middlePoints)
        middlePoints.run(moveDown)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please only post relevant code. Certainly most of what you posted has nothing to do with your error.

Answer (score 7):

### Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable

First of all, we need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) like this:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    let spawn = SKAction.run {
        self.createCars()
    }

    func createCars() { }
}
```

> error: value of type '(NSObject) -> () -> GameScene' has no member 'createCars'

### Problem

The problem happens because you can't populate a property on the same line it is defined using `self` (infact `self` doesn't exist yet).

### Solution

However you can use a lazy property wich will be evaluated only when called (and at that time `self` will be available).

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    lazy var spawn: SKAction = {
        SKAction.run { self.createCars() }
    }()

    func createCars() { }
}
```